# How do I write my Django query when the WHERE clause is meant to have a function?

Tags: python, sql, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm using Django and Python 3.7 along with PostGres 9.5.  I have a column in my PostGres table of type text, which records URLs for articles.  I want to run a query that compares everything before the query string, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM article where regexp_replace(url, '\?.*$', '') = :url_wo_query_info
```

but I'm not sure how to pull this off in Django.  Normally if I want to straigh tup query on just a URL, I could write

```
Article.objects.filter(url=url)
```

BUt I'm unsure how to do the above in Django's lingo because there is a more complicated function involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Func** with F expressions to use database functions on model fields. Your query would look like this in Django ORM:

```
Article.objects.all().annotate(
    processed_url=Func(
        F('url'),
        Value('\?.*$'), Value(''),
        function='regexp_replace',
    )
).filter(processed_url=url_wo_query_info)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Does the "Article.objects.all()" part of the statement actually run a query against the db pulling in all its records and then a second query is run based on the function?

Comment: No, in Django, a query is executed only when you try to use it, i.e read its value or convert it to a list etc. Only the most recent version of the query, after taking all filter, annotate, exclude etc. statements into account, is executed